# I got security updates message when I login to ubuntu but I can't find the updates

Tags: security

I got a message "21 updates are security updates." when I login to my ubuntu server but I can't find the updates. How can I find it and update the security updates. I want to update only the security updates.

```
$ ssh MY_SERVER
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)

204 packages can be updated.
21 updates are security updates.

New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

$ sudo apt-get upgrade -s | grep -i security
// result is empty
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt list --upgradeable | grep -i security`?

Comment: thanks. I checked it now but the result was empty

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Ubuntu's motd is not always accurate when it comes to indicating updates.

What you see when you login with ssh is a dynamically generated motd (message of the day) ; see [How is /etc/motd updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105689/how-is-etc-motd-updated).

You can view this message with :

```
cat /run/motd.dynamic
```

And view an updated version with :

```
sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d
```

I don't really understand why motd is not accurate as it should be updated at every login with `pam_motd`.